# Tensorflow: sparse categorical crossentropy and precision metric incompatibility

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm training a classification model, and I've decided to switch from categorical crossentropy loss function to sparse categorical crossentropy to potentially use less memory and have faster trainings. My training computes precision and recall metrics.

However, when I switch to sparse crossentropy, precision metric starts to fail. The thing is that `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` expects true labels to be scalars, while predicted labels to be vectors of size "number of classes", and precision metrics raises an exception of "shape mistmatch" type.

A minimal example to show this (the same model works without the precision score, and fails during the second training with added precision score computation):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.arange(0, 20)
y = np.zeros_like(x)
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] % 2 == 0:
        y[i] = 0  # Even number
    else:
        y[i] = 1  # Odd number
n_classes = len(np.unique(y))


model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=(1,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)

print("Train without precision metric")
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=2)


print("Train with precision metric")
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Precision()],
)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=2)
```

The output is

```
Metal device set to: Apple M1 Pro
2022-09-20 18:47:20.254419: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:305] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2022-09-20 18:47:20.254522: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:271] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: <undefined>)
2022-09-20 18:47:20.324585: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
Train without precision metric
Epoch 1/2
2022-09-20 18:47:20.441786: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:113] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.

1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.9380
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 205ms/step - loss: 5.9380
Epoch 2/2

1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5.8844
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 5.8844
Train with precision metric
Epoch 1/2

systemMemory: 16.00 GB
maxCacheSize: 5.33 GB

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dima/dev/learn/datascience/test-sparse-precision.py", line 35, in <module>
    model.fit(x, y, epochs=2)
  File "/Users/dima/sw/mambaforge/envs/data-science/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/var/folders/_0/2yc8qfs11xq2vykxzkkngq4m0000gn/T/__autograph_generated_filedw4nh8_p.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/Users/dima/sw/mambaforge/envs/data-science/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/Users/dima/sw/mambaforge/envs/data-science/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/Users/dima/sw/mambaforge/envs/data-science/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/Users/dima/sw/mambaforge/envs/data-science/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 894, in train_step
        return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/Users/dima/sw/mambaforge/envs/data-science/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 987, in compute_metrics
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/Users/dima/sw/mambaforge/envs/data-science/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 501, in update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    File "/Users/dima/sw/mambaforge/envs/data-science/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 70, in decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/dima/sw/mambaforge/envs/data-science/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/metrics/base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/dima/sw/mambaforge/envs/data-science/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/metrics/metrics.py", line 818, in update_state  **
        return metrics_utils.update_confusion_matrix_variables(
    File "/Users/dima/sw/mambaforge/envs/data-science/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 619, in update_confusion_matrix_variables
        y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

It occurs on two different environments: Tensorflow 2.9.2 from Apple for M1, and on Tensorflow 2.8.0 on Ubuntu.

Does anyone know how to deal with this besides writing my own metric class?

Comment: Since you said you're switching from categorical to sparse_categorical, and you're getting a shape mismatch, the most obvious cause could be you're not encoding your labels. One-hot labels are of rank `num_of_classes` but your labels probably aren't the same as what you're trying to train the model on. I don't see where you one-hot encode any labels.

Comment: You need to change how `tf.keras.metrics.Precision` is calculated, it is not implemented for sparse labels, so you can just subclass it and override `update_state()` method.

Comment: @Frightera, yes, thanks! It was kind unexpected that there are incompatibilities like this :-)

Comment: @Djinn For sparse crossentropy one should not one-hot encode the true lables.

Comment: Yeah had the thinking backwards. Meant they should be not using encoded labels.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by you and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy#used-in-the-notebooks), We can use **SparseCategoricalCrossentropy** loss if we have labels as `integers` and **CategoricalCrossentropy** loss if we have labels in `one-hot` representation.

But to fix the above mentioned arror, you can use **binarycrossentropy** loss as there are binary labels(0,1) and change the final layer arguments as below:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=(1,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
    ]
)

print("Train without precision metric")
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="BinaryCrossentropy",
)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=2)
```

Output:

```
Train without precision metric
Epoch 1/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 475ms/step - loss: 0.8964
Epoch 2/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 12ms/step - loss: 0.8776
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f438e6ce190>
```

and to check the precision score:

```
print("Train with precision metric")
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="BinaryCrossentropy",
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Precision()],
)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=2)
```

Output:

```
Train with precision metric
Epoch 1/2
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 636ms/step - loss: 0.8595 - precision: 0.5263
Epoch 2/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 0.8420 - precision: 0.5263
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f438e627e50>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I need to train a multiclass classification model eventually, so the binary cross entropy does not work for me.